# Merge same SQL database values in table and relating table

Tags: sql

sure it could solved  one by one, for each value in specified column but I was looking for an more elegant way, handled by one SQL query.

Following mini database:

Two material tables:

```
Table MatA:
ID  NomCom_ID   ProFo_ID
1   1           1
2   2           2

Table MatB:
ID  NomCom_ID   ProFo_ID
1   1           2
2   2           2
```

One note table:

```
Table Note:
ID  Val MatTab
1   S6  A
2   T1  A
3   W10 A
4   W12 A
5   S5  B
6   T1  B
7   G10 B
8   T1  XXX
9   W10 XXX
10  G8  XXX
```

And one table for relation between notes and Materials:

```
Table RelateNoteMat:
ID  Mat_ID  Note_ID
1   1       1
2   1       2
3   2       2
4   2       3
5   1       8
6   1       10
```

at a later time it's clear, that MatTab 'XXX' is MatTab 'A'
so I want to update Table Note and Table RelateNoteMat like this:

```
Table Note:
ID  Val MatTab
1   S6  A
2   T1  A
3   W10 A
4   W12 A
5   S5  B
6   T1  B
7   G10 B
8   G8  A
```

And one table for relation between notes and Materials:

```
Table RelateNoteMat:
ID  Mat_ID  Note_ID
1   1       1
2   1       2
3   2       2
4   2       3
5   1       8
```

is this possible with one SQL query?

Comment: Is what possible?  I can't quite tell what the question is.

Comment: It is actually unclear what are relation between your tables are. What are `NomCom` and `ProFo` columns? What are notes and materials? What is `Val` and how is it built and related to this question? Please, explain the meaning of it all. Even better use more clear and self-explanatory names so that all other developers and yourself in future can understand it.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...